# How can I set text Button in a Fragment from another Fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a problem with Fragment.

In my Activity i call Fragment1

-> In Fragment1, I call Fragment2

-> In Fragment2, When I click to a button, The text of button in Fragment1 will be changed.(I don't know how to do this)

This is my source code:

activity_main.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnFragment1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Call Fragment 1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnFragment1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
```

fragment1.xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnFragment2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Call Fragment 2" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnFragment2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
```

fragment2.xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnChange"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:text="Change text for button in fragment 1 to 'DONE'" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnFragment2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnFragment1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFragment1);

    btnFragment1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fragment = new Fragment1();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); //lay fragmenttransaction thong qua fragment manager
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.lnFragment1,fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });

}
```

Fragment1.java:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,container,false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Button btnFragment2 = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnFragment2);

    btnFragment2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fragment = new Fragment2();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); //lay fragmenttransaction thong qua fragment manager
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.lnFragment2,fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
}
```

Fragment2.java:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2,container,false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Button btnChange = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnChange);
    btnChange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fragment1 = new Fragment1();
            View vFragment1 = fragment1.getView();
            Button btnChange = (Button) vFragment1.findViewById(R.id.btnChange);
            btnChange.setText("Done");
        }
    });
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: two fragments shouldn't communicate each other directly, use interface to communicate fragment1 to activity, activity to fragment2.

Comment: You Have Required To communicate one Fragment to another fragment You use One Activity .

Answer (score 0):

Make a Contract interface and implement in fragment for communicating between them, fragment can't communicate directly like this.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is Broadcast Manager

**Framgent -1**

In Your Framgent -1

```
private MyBroadRequestReceiver receiver;
```

in onCreateView

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_NAME);
 receiver = new MyBroadRequestReceiver();
registerReceiver( receiver, filter);
```

public class MyBroadRequestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     //update your Button text here

    }


}

@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        this.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

**Fragment-2**

And Call that BroadCast from Fragment-2 
When ever you want to Update Text of First Fragment Button

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction(ACTION_NAME);       
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

Make Sure Action name for both fragment should be same.

Comment: Just go with this it will work for you you can also pass some data in intent while calling sendBroadCast and perform action in onReceive with getting that intent. if you find it useful don't forgot to mark as true,thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don,t take too much pressure . There is a library which will make your work easier. [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) . you can also find good tutorial here [Fragment Refresh](http://blog.tamanneupane.com/fragment-refresh/)